# How to find latest source release of particular minor version of GCC?

Tags: gcc, gcc7

I am building GCC from source for particular target. I would like to use latest GCC 7.2 release.

When I go to official GCC FTP [GCC FTP](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/), I can find only "gcc-7.2.0" release.

But, for example, in [Arch Linux repository](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/gcc/) the latest GCC package is "gcc 7.2.1+20180116-1", which is, I guess, gcc-7.2.1.

So, the question is: where to find official latest source release of particular minor version of GCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC releases with a date are development snapshots. You're not looking at an official release; it's part way between 7.2.0 and 7.3.0.

You can find snapshots tagged in subversion. The website says they're in FTP too.